# Change the name of MultipartFile

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to change the name of MultipartFile.

I'm using MultipartFile on my controller to call rest service:

```
@PostMapping("/post")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
{
    ...
}
```

Have you please any idea about changing the OriginalFilename of the uploaded file ?.

Big thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```
@PostMapping("/post")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
{
    try {
        String filename = "random_filename.pdf"; // Give a random filename here.
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        String insPath = <DIRECTORY PATH> + filename // Directory path where you want to save ;
        Files.write(Paths.get(insPath), bytes);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(filename);
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception here 
    }
}
```

You have to remember to add a random string to the file name. If you just hard code the file name, every time you upload a file, the previous file will be replaced.

Comment: Is rename possible without saving the file to a local directory? Need to upload the received MultipartFile to Azureblob with a custom filename

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve renaming of a file as below. To verify go the uploadDir and you will have a file with `"renameTest"`.

You can append `clientId + uploadTime` to a filename to avoid the same filenames in database

```
@PostMapping(value = "/post")
    public  String renameMultipartFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String uploadDir = "yourPath";
        String filename = "renameTest";
        Path saveTO = Paths.get(uploadDir + filename);
        try {
            try {
                Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), saveTO);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Error : " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return "File uploaded successfully";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error : " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Sir @PatelRomil, thanks a lot. It works also.